# How to add J2C(Java 2 CICS) plug-in to eclipse indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Hi I am new to eclipse and I want to do java web services where I have to use Customer Information Control System(CICS) region as well. So can any one help us how to install J2C plugin to eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

The J2C tooling is only available as part of the Rational Application Developer (RAD) product and so can't be installed into a vanilla eclipse installation.

A free trial of RAD can be downloaded from here -> http://www.ibm.com/software/products/en/application

Information about the features and installing them in RAD is in the knowledge centre -> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSRTLW_9.1.0/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/c_plan_install_feature_product.html